# Visual Studio 2008 Unit Test: How to execute one by one?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

When doing Unit Testing, is there a way to tell the [TestClass()] to execute one [TestMethod()] by one? (Instead of Visual Studio to start multiple thread). This would be required for only one or two of my testing classes.

Comment: Why don't you want it to test all at once?

Comment: Because I have a lot of TestMethod and they verify a global variable status and I do not want other test to intefere.

Comment: I have wondered this myself...

Comment: This illustrates pretty well why global data is considered evil in relation to unit testing. It probably doesn't help you in any way right now, but the reason unit testing tools generally tend not to provide features like the one you ask for is because they explicitly discourages such designs.

Comment: You have case that you require to have global variable. I am sorry that you do not see the utility cause in a perfect world you are right but in the world I live, it's not. Example, if you have some input and output has files. You might not want 2 tests to run in same time (creation/delete file)? Etc. They are many other example that require to have one test to be executed after one and not in concurrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this in Visual Studio 2008 using the default tools.

It is possible by adding some ... interesting configuration code to the TestInit method. For instance, you could have all of your test classes derive from the following base class.

```
[TestClass]
public class ExecuteOneAtTimeBase {
  private static object s_mutex = new object();

  [TestInit]
  public void TestInit() {
    Monitor.Enter(s_mutex);
  }

  [TestCleanup]
  public void TestCleanup() {
    Monitor.Exit(s_mutex);
  }
}
```

All TestMethod instances are bracketed by calls to TestInit and TestCleanup methods.  Using the Monitor.Enter/Exit combo you can guarantee that a given unit test method holds the lock for the duration of it's execution.  Therefore multiple threads cannot be running different tests at the same time in a single AppDomain.

There are error cases where this could lead to a deadlock in the testing process.  But I think that is probably a minor concern as it's not production code.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Visual Studio 2008 Team Suite or (I believe) one of the Tester editions, you can create an Ordered Test and add all your unit test to that Ordered Test.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug or run any single TestMethod.

- Put your cursor in a TestMethod
- to debug: Ctrl-R, Ctrl-T   or Test -> Debug -> Tests In Current Context
- to run: Ctrl-R, T   or Test -> Run-> Tests In Current Context

Comment: This is really not what I want... If I have 2000 tests and only 100 needs to be run 1 by 1. I won't do it manually.